Movie or series involving an alien disguised as a child in the woods
I watched a movie or maybe a series in the 90s about grays on Earth. In one instance, there is a child in the woods and he is followed by another child who spots him. The first reaches a lake where there is a spaceship. When he turns around, it is actually an alien disguised with a wig. Then, in another instance, they seem to be disguised as electricians, but I was a little girl to remember the name or other details.

Is this Intruders (1992)...?

All over the world, people report being visited by aliens, taken aboard spaceships and clinically examined. Authorities seem to know all about these visitations but will not admit it publicly.

It's a 161-minute miniseries about a California-based psychiatrist dealing with traumatised patients who've seemingly been abducted and experimented on by little grey men in flying saucers. The psychiatrist, Dr. Neil Chase, uses hypnotic regression on these patients to help them uncover supressed memories of their experiences.
In an early scene, a woman relates an experience where she was woken up in the early hours of the morning by what appeared to be a phone company truck parking outside her house. Four shadowy figures in overalls then emerged from the truck, somehow walked through the walls of her house and abducted her, taking her to a spaceship.



In a later scene, a different woman relates a childhood experience where she and another young girl were beckoned into the woods by a boy whose face they couldn't see clearly. They chased him through the woods to a lake, where they saw a flying saucer hovering above the water. The boy then turned his head too look at them, revealing a grey alien face with black eyeballs.




You can find the whole thing on YouTube, but here's a trailer.




Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/291071/23243
